# How to access wordpress custom post type Object

Tags: php, wordpress, object, custom-post-type

Please Help:

I am getting this Custom Post type Object within Wordpress. This is actually what print_r($this) returns.

**How can I get the content of 'key', for example?**

```
Post_Types Object ( 
    [post_types_definition:Post_Types:private] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [key] => solutions 
            [name] => Solutions 
            [taxonomies] => Array ( ) 
            [categories] => 
            [show_in_nav_menus] => 
            [settings] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [title] => Solutions settings field 
                    [description] => Solutions settings field 
                    [type] => text 
                    [properties] => Array ( 
                        [text-id] => solutions_settings_field_2 
                    )    
                )    
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Any help is highly appreciated it!

Comment: What is the context of $this?

Comment: print_r($this) outputs exactly what listed above

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. We need more code to go on. It seems that $this actually refers to the object you're trying to access??

Comment: Exactly. Now, how can I get the content of 'key' or 'name'?

Comment: Can you do a get_object_vars() on `$this`?

Comment: Omg. It was that simple.... Thank you!

Comment: Haha, you are welcome. I'll post an answer. If you could mark as the answer and possibly upvote, I'd appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `get_object_vars()` on your `$this` to get the variables available to you. From there, you should be able to access the variable by its name through your instance like so:

```
$this->my_variable
```

Unless this is a dynamically-created variable, you should be able to simply look at the code, especially considering this is such a simple object. However, if you are ever in a pickle, I find this particularly helpful.